# How to deal with a cross-posted question which belongs to SU ?

Tags: support, questions, migration, exact-duplicates

Some days ago, I posted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/191028/).

This is a cross-post from Ubuntu SE. [The question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4422/) has also been answered.

I now know that cross-posting is discouraged. However, *I think* it belongs here. IMO, The options for dealing with are as follows:

2. Close the question as being exact duplicate of the Ubuntu SE question.
3. Answer the question with link to the Ubuntu SE answer and accept it.
4. Migrate from Ubuntu SE into SU.
5. Close / delete this question and let the question+answer remain in Ubuntu SE. This is the preferred option is consensus opinion is that it belongs more in Ubuntu SE than SU.
6. Anything else ?

Can u pls help me decide what the next step should be ?

Comment: More generally, see [What is the etiquette regarding asking a question again on another Stack Exchange site?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2086/what-is-the-etiquette-regarding-asking-a-question-again-on-another-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until new SE-site are out of beta, there's no way to migrate or refer to them, so all those options are off.

Referring to the current url might create dead links over time, so I wouldn't encourage that either.

Also remember that our main access point is Google, so it doesn't on what site it's at, as long as there's a great answer to the question **somewhere** on our network of sites.

So my advice, don't worry and have fun over at Ubuntu SE :-)

Comment: thanks for that. Will go by your advice & have lots of fun :-).

Comment: 1. Moderators can now migrate to U&L or AU or Apple. 2. The [official SE policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71938/can-i-cross-post-my-question-from-one-site-to-another/71949#71949) is that cross-posting is not allowed. Does SU follow this policy? 3. This particular question is answered on AU, I don't see the point of keeping it on SU.

Comment: Could you elaborate on google being your main access point. I've heard at several times and it doesn't really make sense to me with respect to cross posting.

Comment: @bmike, if you type in a question and its answered on our network, it doesn't matter where its answered. You'll find it through Google and that's all that matters. 80% of our traffic comes through Google

Comment: So that penalizes me for using the search form on say "ask different" since I don't get the benefit of all the answered mac questions that already have an answer or a better answer on superuser. Why doesn't SE use the main access point (aka google)  in the site search?

Comment: You should search on Stack Exchange.com for searching across the network

Comment: I had no idea that was possible. I'll try it even though it injects ads by google and means I have to click off the site to another page to search for an answer before posting a question.

Comment: I don't see ads here: http://stackexchange.com/search