# What is the etiquette regarding asking a question again on another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, support

I've asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/242627/how-does-office-2008-for-mac-store-its-recent-items) on SuperUser before I realised that [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) existed. I feel that my question would be better served on the the Ask Different Stack Exchange site. How should I go about moving it?

- I could add a message to the original question asking if someone with the appropriate capabilities could migrate it.
- I could just leave it where it is and ask the question again on the other site.

Is there another option that is considered to be better?

What is the best practice / etiquette regarding this situation?

Comment: Note that the [official SE policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71938/can-i-cross-post-my-question-from-one-site-to-another/71949#71949) is that cross-posting is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general: It's better to ask a question at one Stack Exchange site. If you feel that your question is not getting decent feedback/answers/views - just flag for Moderator attention asking to Migrate to the relevant Stack Exchange.

You might want to wait for a day or two before flagging for Mod. attention, though just to give it exposure for a while.

Please do not cross-post!

---

WRT: Your linked question: Questions on Mac related software are on-topic on Super User. I've edited your question, cleaned up the formatting a bit and it has been bumped up. If you haven't any responses, do feel free to flag for Mod attention and ask for Migration to Ask Different.

Comment: it is ok to re-ask so long as the question is framed for the audience, and **the original question is deleted** (I'm assuming it has no answers)

Answer (score -2):

There is another option: *split your question into multiple parts*, and ask on every site that part which is more related to the given site.

You can also link the questions together, which results cross-visits and makes more attractive for the answerers thinking on the same way as you.

With the timing of your questions you can also tune your learning process and the sites behaviors to eachother (for example, asking part1 on site1, and using the information you've learned to ask part2 on site2).

Last time I've did it on the [Codegolf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/143016/14149) and the [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2432123/111704).

This makes possible for you to get answers from multiple viewpoints, on each site from the more specialists of the given topic.

Furthermore, asking a question means typically many related discussion, making your question more clear, comments below your question and the answer(s), and so on. The information what you get on the sites, can be very useful also on the others.

Note, asking a question *correctly* is typically harder as answering a question for which you know an answer. Doing this with multiple questions on different site, requires from you to know all the sites well.